# Setting file upload contents using script

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload

Is there a way to use JavaScript to set the file name and contents of a form's file uploads?

For example, suppose we have two file input elements.

```
<input type="file">
<input type="file">
```

Can JavaScript copy the content from one form element to the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Add an `onchange` event on any of the input type file

Get its file property and assign to other input like

```
element2.files = element1.files;
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById("1");
var el1 = document.getElementById("2");
el.onchange = function(){
el1.files = el.files;
 

}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="1">
<input type="file" id="2">
```